# How Do You Use Transparent Video In Blender Video Editor?

Tags: import, transparency, video-sequence-editor, video

Every time I import a video with transparency in the Blender video editor, the transparent parts show up as black. The transparency works fine on other video editors. I also did turn on alpha over. There is a similar thread about this, but there are no solutions besides converting the video into an image sequence, which could be a pain to do every time you need to use the video.

Comment: please add a blend file so we can check it out

Comment: Try with png in a .mov container.